# How to set value to multiple variables in one line in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, npm

I tried to do something like this (see **build:dev**):
[image]

also tried to do this:
**set var1=a && set var2=b**

still don't work.
Tell please how can I do it?

Comment: In Windows cmd.exe, or a batch file, the correct syntax for defining multiple variables on the same line would be this: ```Set "var1=a" & Set "var2=b" & Set "var3=c"```. However, there is no need to join lines in this manner in a batch file, not only are there command line length limits, it does not make the code any more efficient or easier to read.

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 0):

I would set each variable on a separate line, all following the same format.

```
    @echo off
    set names=Hirsty
    set source=StackOverflow
    echo Hello %names% - possible answer from %source%
```

This would give an output of:

[image: Output]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use single `&` :

```
set "var1=a" & set "var2=b"
echo My two variables: %var1% %var2%
```

Output:

```
C:\>set "var1=a" & set "var2=b"

C:\>echo My two variables: %var1% %var2%
My two variables: a  b

C:\>
```

Comment: this sets `var1` to `a `, not `a` as expected. Always use the `set "var=value"` form to avoid things like this